# Python Inheritence - Parent Object as parameter to child object

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I am having some issues with an inheritence model. i want to create a new child object from  a given parent object and i would like to access those properties.
Here is a simplified model of my structure.

```
class foo:
def __init__(self,id,name):
    self.id = id
    self.name = name

class bar(foo):
    pass

new = foo(id='1',name='Rishabh')

x = bar(new)

print(x.name)
```

I want all the attributes from the new object to be inherited in the x object.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried importing copy and then  x=copy.copy(new)

Comment: HI Banny Thanks for the reply. I just tried copy after your suggestion. but i was still wondering if there was any feature that allowed inheriting the object as a parameter.

Comment: What you are describing as "inheriting" isn't inheritance in the object-oriented sense, it is in fact much more like copying.

Comment: Alrighty then.. I guess I have some reading to do there.. Thanks for your help

Comment: See @wenckisa's answer, it's pretty hard to use - much easier to use copy.

Answer (score 2):

At first, as [PEP8 Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) says, **"Class names should normally use the CapWords convention."** So you should rename your classes to be `Foo` and `Bar`.

Your task can be done by using [`object.__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) and by overriding the `__init__` method in your child class (`Bar`)

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name


class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Here we override the constructor method
        # and pass all the arguments to the parent __init__()

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


new = Foo(id='1',name='Rishabh')

x = Bar(**new.__dict__)
# new.__dict__() returns a dictionary
# with the Foo's object instance properties:
# {'id': '1', 'name': 'Rishabh'}

# Then you pass this dictionary as
# **new.__dict__
# in order to resolve this dictionary into keyword arguments
# for the Bar __init__ method

print(x.name)  # Rishabh
```

But this is not a conventional way of doing things. If you want to have an instance, that is a copy of another, you should probably use the `copy` module and do not do this overkill.

Comment: I guess i will go for copy then

Comment: beautifully xplained. +1